# HTML: how to specify the label to anchor element in the context of accessbility

Tags: html, jaws-screen-reader

Here is the requirement:
I have an anchor element which represent the link.

```
<a href ="login.html">3</a>
```

Currently Screen reader(JAWS) is announcing it as **"Link 3"**
But I want to make screen reader to read it as **"Link 3 Login Page"**

To make it work I added title attribute to anchor element.

```
<a href ="login.html" title="Login Page">3</a>
```

Now its announcing as **"Link 3 Login Page"**

But problem is..As per accessbility guidelines using "title" attribute is not recommeneded since its failing in most of the screen reader and browsers combination.

I used "aria-label" instead then in this case its reading only "Login page".

```
<a href ="login.html" aria-label="Login Page">3</a>
```

How to make screen reader reads both **"Link 3 and Login Page"**

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this :

```css
.screenreader {
    position: absolute !important; /* Outside the DOM flow */
    height: 1px; width: 1px; /* Nearly collapsed */
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE 7+ only support clip without commas */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /* All other browsers */
}
```

```html
<a href ="login.html">3 <span class="screenreader">- Login page</span></a>
```

Your screen reader will read it like "Link 3 - Login page" but your user while only see "3"

Comment: Is there any other way without using css?

Comment: Yep, what about `aria-label="Link 3 Login Page"` ? It will be read like it, that what you want too ?

Comment: It works but It requires a extra string concatnation operation and currently there are 100's of links. More importantly when Jaws reads it will read entire string at one shot without any pause. Hope you understand my concern here.

Comment: I know that some screen reader take care of the punctuation, may `aria-label="Link 3, Login Page"` will work ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Clement has it right here without using CSS - just add some punctuation to the aria label. Aria-label="Link 3. Login Page" should do it. Good luck!